# How do I look for my Server Name for SQL Server Managment Studio v17. RC1?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I need to establish a connection, but I need to provide my `Server Name` and it seems that I keep getting it wrong. I tried using `Command Prompt` and the command `ipconfig` and use the `Ip` as the Server Name as someone told me to do, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you trying to connect to the local machine (same as where management studio is installed)? If so you can just use `localhost`. Otherwise, you need to find out the hostname of the machine where SQL server is installed. If you don't know it, you can either a) ask whoever maintains the server, or, if you have the IP address, `ping -a <ip_addr>` might reveal it

Comment: Always remember that SSMS <> SQL Server. Is SQL installed on the same machine? If not, is it on a Windows or Linux box? (And yes, can't believe I'm asking that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking on local machine, Server name is localhost or machine name and do check in windows services that your SQL Server service is running.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for Windows SQL Servers, haven't tried it on Linux yet...
Running sqlcmd -Lc at a command prompt will give you a list of available SQL Servers. If you've installed SQL as a default instance, servername should suffice. If you've installed a named instance, then it's servername\instancename.